Irssi: Howto suppress output of internal irrssi commands when run from script?
I'm writing an Irssi script that will apply themes based on arbitrary conditions. To set the theme from inside the script I'm using Irssi::command("SET theme $theme_file");. This generates output identical to when the user would invoke the /set theme command.
How can I suppress this output?

To suppress the command's output in a script I need to add '^' before the command.
Example:
Irssi::command("^SET theme $theme_file");
